# Why is aerodynamic drag independent of mass?- intuition

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, drag, intuition

What is the intuition behind the formula for aerodynamic drag and why it doesn't include the mass of the object? It seems to me that the falling object would exert a force on each particle in the air that is causing the drag force, and that this force would depend on the mass of the object?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are confusing definitions and the way you are connecting dependencies.

Aerodynamic drag is dependent on speed, and speed can be dependent on many things.

> It seems to me that the falling object would exert a force on each particle in the air that is causing the drag force, and that this force would depend on the mass of the object?

I am not sure if your falling objects is just an example or if it slipped your mind that aerodynamic drag applies to more than falling objects, so I am just going to point out that aerodynamic drag doesn't only apply to falling objects. It applies to *moving* objects.

If you are only picturing falling objects, the confusion might be coming from only picturing falling objects which involve the force of gravity, whose force is proportional to the mass of an object out of the picture.

Take an example where forces other than gravity are involved: think of the thrust from a jet engine pushing a plane along. Does that break your current mental model of more force being applied to the air particles just because the airplane is heavier or lighter?

What if we make it even simpler than that and just take your example but remove gravity? Picture a rock that has been thrown and is moving through an air-filled space station in zero Gs. There's no force on it anymore because gravity is absent and it has already left the person's hand. It still has mass but has no weight, and no force behind it. Would it have less drag in your mind?

---

As for why mass does not, or rather, *cannot* come into it, the flaw in your reasoning might be that the force exerted on the object to move it is the same as the force exerted on the air. It is not.

**Why mass *cannot* come into it:**

The air itself only knows the speed the object is moving at (and its shape by virtue of the the direction it is being pushed by the object). The air cannot know the mass of the object because the air's only interaction with the object is collisions at the surface. There is no way for it to determine the mass behind that surface any more than you can touch a wall and determine how heavy everything attached behind the wall is. Even if it was a moving wall that slowed down when it collided with you, you still could not know the mass of the wall from the change in speed since for all you know, it could be a feather weight wall with lots of propulsive force behind it or a super heavy wall on a ballistic trajectory with no force behind it.

Comment: But in the formula, the mass of the particles exerting the drag is important, as it increases inertia and results in resistance to the object's path. "The air cannot know the mass of the object because the air's only interaction with the object is collisions at the surface." How would you explain why the mass of the particles in the air is important?

Comment: I understand that drag is a result of the object's motion, but it is a force and must in some way depend on the force exerted by the falling object, yet I cannot find where in the formula this force is contained in.

Comment: @ten1o I guess I would say that the difference is that each air particles is small enough and alone enough that it can fully respond to the object's surface and is locally displaced. The surface of the object is not displaced by individual air particles. And what if the object is not falling? What if the object is just sitting there and the air is blowing against it? Or what if the object is in a zero G ballistic trajectory? Do you expect the drag to be different? Because in those cases the there is no force propelling the mass.

Answer (score 0):

In fluid dynamics, drag (sometimes called air resistance, a type of friction, or fluid resistance, another type of friction or fluid friction) is a force acting opposite to the relative motion of any object moving with respect to a surrounding fluid.[1] This can exist between two fluid layers (or surfaces) or a fluid and a solid surface. Unlike other resistive forces, such as dry friction, which are nearly independent of velocity, drag force depends on velocity.
Drag force is proportional to the velocity for a laminar flow and the squared velocity for a turbulent flow. Even though the ultimate cause of a drag is viscous friction, the turbulent drag is independent of viscosity